# Resource/materials for learning about quantum computer hardware

Tags: hardware

I am chemical engineering undergraduate (currently in 3 year).
I do have interest in quantum computer hardware.

I have read

1. Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Isaac Chuang and Michael Nielsen
2. Quantum Mechanics: The Theoretical Minimum by Leonard Susskind
3. A Modern Approach to Quantum Mechanics by Townsend
4. Principles of Quantum Mechanics Textbook by Ramamurti Shankar
   I also know ML.

**Please let me know about the available recourses/materials to learn quantum computer hardware in depth**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the architecture of Fault-Tolerant Quantum Computer, read: [Surface codes: Towards practical large-scale quantum computation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0928) it will guide you through the basics of every type of hardware.

For a deep understanding of each technology:

1. The best for Superconducting Qubits is ["A Quantum Engineer's Guide to Superconducting Qubits"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.06560)
2. For photonic quantum computer, you should read [Five Lectures on Optical Quantum Computing](https://www.pieter-kok.staff.shef.ac.uk/docs/LNP787_187.pdf)

Those are the best I know for those 2 types of hardware